# need help for display sdcard's mp3 files into list view using android

Tags: android, listview, mp3, sd-card

I need to display downloaded mp3 files into the Listview and also want to put validation like once any mp3 file has downloaded then user should get message "already downloaded" if that mp3 is exist into the sdcard.

Can any one give me idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File bookFile = new File("/sdcard/"+filename);
        if(bookFile.exists())
        {

            System.out.println("Downloaded");

        }
        else
        {
                     System.out.println("want to Download");
        }
```